# How to obtain a correct image of a ComboChart with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a SpreadSheet template that contains a ComboChart inside, one series type column, another type line.

When I try to export the chart with Google Apps Script, the image exported doesn't show the columns (appears as a line).

Basically, I open the sheet, change the values in a range in particular, update the chart and then capture the chart as image.

My Google Apps Script function is this:

```
var hardcodedData = {
  data:  [['Muy Bajo', 0.1, 20],
          ['Bajo', 0.2, 32],
          ['Medio Bajo', 0.15, 51],
          ['Medio', 0.05, 42],
          ['Medio Alto', 0.07, 30],
          ['Alto', 0.23, 15],
          ['Muy Alto', 0.2, 11]],
  fileId : 'id-of-spreadsheet-template'
}

function chartBuilder() {

  var hdd = hardcodedData.data;

  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(hardcodedData.fileId);
  var sh = sp.getSheets()[0];
  sh.getRange('C2:D8').clearContent();

  var clasific = [];
  var ndvi = [];
  var has = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < hdd.length; i++) {
    ndvi    .push([hdd[i][1]]);
    has     .push([hdd[i][2]]);
  }
  sh.getRange(2, 3, 7, 1).setValues(ndvi);
  sh.getRange(2, 4, 7, 1).setValues(has);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var chart = sh.getCharts()[0];  
  sh.updateChart(chart);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  chart = sh.getCharts()[0];

  var myimage = chart.getAs('image/gif');

  //fill document------------------------------------------
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('id-of-document')
  doc.getBody().clear();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph("");

  body.insertImage(0, myimage)
}
```

Is there any way to open and export the chart image correctly, the way it's in the spreadsheet template?

Sorry for the poor context, I don't have the reputation to post images.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar problem, it appears as though the Chart.getAs(contentType) method ignores some of the styling and options that are set for the EmbeddedChart objects.

It's not a perfect solution, but I've found a workaround, through the Slides Apps Script service, although it requires having a blank 'proxy presentation' set up to pass charts through.

[Slide.insertSheetsChartAsImage(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertSheetsChartAsImage(EmbeddedChart)) will give you the chart correctly displayed as an image within a slides presentation, and you can then use the image from there.

```js
function chartBuilder() {

  // ...

  var chart = sh.getCharts()[0];  
  sh.updateChart(chart);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  chart = sh.getCharts()[0];

  // Insert sheets chart into slide as an embedded image
  var proxySaveSlide = SlidesApp.openById("my-blank-sheets-presentation").getSlides()[0];
  var chartImage = proxySaveSlide.insertSheetsChartAsImage(chart);

  // Get image from slides
  var myimage = chartImage.getAs('image/png');


  //fill document------------------------------------------
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('id-of-document');
  doc.getBody().clear();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph("");

  body.insertImage(0, myimage);

 // Delete image in presentation slide
 chartImage.remove();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## Saving Chart Images in a Folder as png

```
function saveImage() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Sheet where your chart is
  var charts=sh.getCharts();
  var blob=charts[0].getAs('image/png');//just have one
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');//folder Id
  folder.createFile(blob).setName('Image Name');//Image name
}
```

- [Class Chart Method: getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart#getAs(String))

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I'm looking for. An image is generated and saved in a document by the script, but it's wrong. The colums appear as a line.