# Getting gsheet Combo Charts to send them by email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

This is my first question here, though I've had some helpful guidance from lots of questions before. I hope I don't miss anything important in this question.

I am currently writing a script in Google Apps Script to send some charts from a Google Sheets document by email, as images. My issue is that with [Combined Charts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142593#combo_chart), when I try to read them and get them as images, I get an error.

I've reduced the code to the minimum that will still throw the error I'm talking about.

```
function test_chart_fails(){
  let gdoc_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  let sheet_name = "test2";
  let document = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gdoc_id);
  let sheet = document.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  let charts = sheet.getCharts();
  let chart = charts[2];
  let inLineImages = {};
  inLineImages["chartC"] = chart.getAs('image/png');
}
```

I get the following error:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
> test_chart_fails  @ AppsScriptFile.gs:305

Where 305 is the last line of my sample code (the one with 'chart.getAs').

Now some additional info that may be relevant (or not):

The sheet in question has 9 charts in total. I get this error if I try to access 7 of the 9, which are only the combined charts. Other charts will work fine, and I can put them in an email sent through MailApp. All the charts were created manually in the Gsheets document.
Regarding the data in the sheet that builds the charts, the sheet has 103 rows and 44 columns. All data in the sheet is formulas, not values.

I've searched for existing questions in this and other sites where this error message appears, but I didn't find a question where the error was related to Chart retrieval - specifically no instance related to Combo Charts. One instance mentioned an error related to the sheet size, so I mentioned the data size (rows x columns), but I don't think that is the issue - because the script runs fine for non-Combo Charts based on the same dataset.

Is this expected for combined charts? Is there a way I can 'retrieve' them and send them in an email like I do the others?

Comment: Are you able to share a sample sheet where this happens? I just tried opening a new spreadsheet and inserting a combochart, then running your code, did not produce any errors for me.

Comment: As I further looked into this, I found that the error comes up with charts where one of the data series is set to display on the second Y-axis. I found that this happens even with non-Combo charts (e.g. Line charts with two Y-axis variables, one on the left and the other on the right).

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084215/how-to-obtain-a-correct-image-of-a-combochart-with-google-app-script/60487108#60487108
and it helped. It's a workaround through Slides for charts with thhe error - copy the chart from Gsheet to Slides, and get the image from Slides, then remove the chart from Slides. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This appears to be a bug

> ### https://issuetracker.google.com/182701055

> #### `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName().getCharts().getAs()` returns this error: "Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id" ... when the line chart has a right vertical axis

I would encourage you to go and star this issue to let Google know that it affects you and to subscribe to updates.

You are also encouraged to post any further reproduction steps and workarounds there if they haven't been mentioned yet.

#### Workaround you mentioned

[How to obtain a correct image of a ComboChart with Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084215/how-to-obtain-a-correct-image-of-a-combochart-with-google-app-script/60487108#60487108)